# Convert DateTime to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert a `DateTime` instance into a `TimeSpan` instance, is it possible?

I've looked around but I couldn't find what I want, I only find time difference. More specifically, I want to convert a `DateTime` instance into milliseconds, to then save it into an IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To convert a `DateTime` to a `TimeSpan` you should choose a base date/time - e.g. midnight of January 1st, 2000, and subtract it from your `DateTime` value (and add it when you want to convert back to `DateTime`).

If you simply want to convert a `DateTime` to a number you can use the [`Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) property.

Answer (score 272):

You can just use the TimeOfDay property of date time, which is TimeSpan type:

```
DateTime.TimeOfDay
```

This property has been around since .NET 1.1

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay || DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay

Comment: To be painfully & overly clear, you'd use `DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;` or whatever to get something into a *specific instance of `DateTime`*, then you can use **`myDateTime.TimeOfDay;`**. Alternately, you can cut out the middleman & say, **`DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay`**, natch. (That is, `DateTime.TimeOfDay`, the current example code, is "invalid" & won't give you a value the same way `DateTime.UtcNow` does, which makes some sense. You need a specific `DateTime` to grab its `TimeOfDay` value.)

Comment: A word of caution. Using this property will give you, and I quote MSDN, a "time interval that represents the fraction of the day that has elapsed since midnight." There may be times when all you care is about the current day. Other times, you may want to get an "absolute" time (for example, if your values span several days or weeks), in which case @MiMo's suggestion to pick a base would be appropriate.

Comment: DateTime.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh\\:mm") to format nicely.

Answer (score 51):

```
TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks)
```

Comment: DateTime.TimeOfDay is better

Comment: That depends. `TimeOfDay` is only the Time and does not include that current date in the `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 15):

Try the following code.

```
 TimeSpan CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

Get the time of the day and assign it to `TimeSpan` variable.

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using WPF and Xceed's TimePicker (which seems to be using DateTime?) as a timespan picker -as I do right now- you can get the total milliseconds (or a TimeSpan) out of it like so:

```
var milliseconds = DateTimeToTimeSpan(timePicker.Value).TotalMilliseconds;

    TimeSpan DateTimeToTimeSpan(DateTime? ts)
    {
        if (!ts.HasValue) return TimeSpan.Zero;
        else return new TimeSpan(0, ts.Value.Hour, ts.Value.Minute, ts.Value.Second, ts.Value.Millisecond);
    }
```

XAML :

```
<Xceed:TimePicker x:Name="timePicker" Format="Custom" FormatString="H'h 'm'm 's's'" />
```

If not, I guess you could just adjust my DateTimeToTimeSpan() so that it also takes 'days' into account or do sth like `dateTime.Substract(DateTime.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds`.