# How to insert only time in ms access?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetimepicker

This is the query I am having issues with:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand(insert into tbl_Customer(cReportingTime) values (@ReportingTime)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReportingTime", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = Time;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I try to run it I am getting this error:

```
"Failed to convert parameter value from a DateTime to a TimeSpan"
```

I want to insert only time in MS Access database however I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime to TimeSpan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959440/convert-datetime-to-timespan)

Comment: @fk2 It may be but I haven't found the answer from that question I had already seen and I got confused where to write Timeofday property. there was no Idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `Time` is a `DateTime`, you can use it's [`TimeOfDay` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReportingTime", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = Time.TimeOfDay;
```

Since `DBTYPE_DBTIME` mapped with `TimeSpan`, this should work.