# Convert a DateTime in TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, datetime

I've a `GCalendar` class that interact with `Google Calendar API`:

```
public class GEvent
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

how you can see there are two properties `StartTime` and `EndTime` that is both `TimeSpan`.

Now I've created an object that instantiates this class, like so:

```
Calendar.GEvent eventD = new Calendar.GEvent();
```

I take the value of the `StartTime` and `EndTime` from a custom control. This control  however return a `DateTime` instead of a `TimeSpan`, so I need to convert the `DateTime` into `TimeSpan`. This is what I did:

```
eventD.StartTime = new TimeSpan((long)EventTimeStart.SelectedTime.Value);
```

where `EventTimeStart` is the custom control. Now there is a problem the `new TimeSpan` waiting for a long, so I tried to implicit cast the control value into `(long)` but I get:

> Cannot convert the type `System.DateTime` into 'Long'

I also tried with:

```
long startTime = EventTimeStart.SelectedTime.Value;
```

but is the same thing. How can I do for fix this?

[image]

Comment: `yourDateTime.TimeOfDay`. You cant `convert` DateTime into Timespan as TimeSpan is part of DateTime. Its like trying to convert a car into a wheel.

Comment: @C4ud3x I doens't have `TimeOfDay` on `EventTimeStart.`

Comment: Then, `EventTimeStart` isnt a DateTime!?

Comment: @C4ud3x ok I found the property was on `EventTimeStart.SelectedTime.Value.TimeOfDay` but the compiler tell me: `Cannot Convert System.TimeSpan to Long`

Comment: A TimeSpan is a time between two DateTime objects.  DateTime in Net library starts at Jan 1, 1900.  There are a few things I can't tell from your posting. 1) Does StartDate and EndDate contain hours and minutes or are  they the Time at Midnight?  Is StartTime and EndTime just the hours and minutes from Midnight or are they the time from Jan 1, 1900?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime to TimeSpan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959440/convert-datetime-to-timespan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

`TimeSpan startTime = EventTimeStart.SelectedTime.Value.TimeOfDay;`

As TimeSpan is a part of DateTime, you cant convert. But you can pick it up with `.TimeOfDay`.

**According the error in the comments:** Dont try to store `TimeSpan` in `long`.
`long time = something.TimeOfDay;` wont work.